# How to install VS2012 for windows phone in my x86 OS? How to convert Windows 8 pro from x86 to x64?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I downloaded a x86 windows pro version and installed in my system.  The mistake which i did is my system supports x64 but by mistake took a msdn x86 version of Windows 8 pro.

Because of installing x86 os i am not able to install visual studio 2012 for windows phone. It throws an error stating that ur system is x86.

It would be of great help if u can give solutions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to uninstall the x86 Windows 8, and install the x64 version to fix that sort of error.

Comment: Can i use the same key. will be it a issue.

Comment: I think you will be able too. at worst you will have to phone Microsoft and explain your situation, but they should let you. You may want to do a quick google before trying.

Comment: the key is the same for both x86 and x64